# Saving Tensorflow model that uses BatchNorm

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to save a generator model from a GAN using Tensorflow. The model I am using has several batch norm layers. When I save the weights, I can only restore them successfully if I run a global variables initializer, which I shouldn't have to do because all the variables are being restored. If I do run the global variables initializer before restoring, when I run inference with the loaded weights and set is_training=False for the batch norm parameter, the model performs very poorly. However, if is_training=True, the model performs as expected. This behavior should be exactly opposite.

To save the weights, I do:

```
t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'g_' in var.name]
g_saver = tf.train.Saver(g_vars)
... train model ...
g_saver.save(sess, "weights/generator/gen.ckpt")
```

When I restore the weights, I use the same model definition and do the following:

```
t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'g_' in var.name]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

g_saver = tf.train.Saver(g_vars)
g_saver.restore(sess, "./weights/generator/gen.ckpt")
```

Is there a special procedure you need to do to account for the batch norm weights? Am I missing some collection of variables?

EDIT:

I define batch norm layer using:

```
conv1_norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv1, is_training=training
```

I found that adding variables_collections=["g_batch_norm_non_trainable"] to the batch_norm function, then doing

```
g_vars = list(set([var for var in t_vars if 'g_' in var.name] + tf.get_collection("g_batch_norm_non_trainable")))
```

works, but this seems quite complicated for what should be a simple weight saving instruction.

Comment: How do you define the batch norm layers? Could please add this part or a example of one batch norm layer to your question?

Comment: I just added an edit, let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a batch normalization with [tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm)  and with the default parameters as it seems is your case, three variables are created: `beta`, `moving_mean`, and `moving_variance`. The first is the only trainable variable, the other two are included in the `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` collection.

That is why `g_vars` defined using the trainable variables at the following line does not get both `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` in the list:

```
g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if 'g_' in var.name]
```

Since it seems that you only want to save the generator variables, I recommend the use of variable scopes to define your generator network.

Example of upsampling a random tensor and using batch normalization:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (2, 7, 7, 64))  # (batch, height, width, in_channels)

with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    # define your generator network here ...
    t_conv_layer = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(input_layer,
                    filters=32, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=(2, 2), padding='SAME', name='t_conv_layer')

    batch_norm = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(t_conv_layer, is_training=True, scope='my_batch_norm')
    print(batch_norm) # Tensor("generator/my_batch_norm/FusedBatchNorm:0", shape=(2, 14, 14, 32), dtype=float32)
```

You can check the list of variables of both `tf.trainable_variables()` and `tf.global_variables()` by printing them.
Since the trainable variables are in the global variables list as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys), we can define `g_vars` as:

```
g_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='generator')
```

If we check this list, we will have all variables for batch norm that we want:

```
for var in g_vars:
    print("variable_name: {:45}, nb_parameters: {}".format(var.name, np.prod(var.get_shape().as_list())))
```

which produces the output:

```
variable_name: generator/t_conv_layer/kernel:0              , nb_parameters: 18432
variable_name: generator/t_conv_layer/bias:0                , nb_parameters: 32
variable_name: generator/my_batch_norm/beta:0               , nb_parameters: 32
variable_name: generator/my_batch_norm/moving_mean:0        , nb_parameters: 32
variable_name: generator/my_batch_norm/moving_variance:0    , nb_parameters: 32
```

Comment: This actually does not work. when I define the generator under a single scope as you did, then collect the variables and load the weights, I get a "key not found: generator/batchnorm/beta/Adam" error... do you know what causes this?

Comment: That is odd. It is working for me. I am defining the generator and `g_vars` as in the answer, and  `saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=g_vars)`. Then, when restoring with `saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(dir_ckpt_file))` the model is restored. Could you share a minimal example to reproduce your error?

Comment: SOLVED: using saver.restore(sess, path/to/model.ckpt) caused the error... but using the tf.train.latest_checkpoint(path/to/dir) worked...